# how to add custom signup fields to react-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

hi all im trying to add a custom user field to react , im trying to make seperate user table in db with the signed up users id. however am getting an error saying that user.uid is undefined for some reason. Can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SignUpView from "./SignUpView";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import app from "../config/dev";
import { UserRef, timeRef } from '../components/reference';
class SignUpContainer extends Component {
  handleSignUp = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { email, password,rank } = event.target.elements;


    try {
      const user = await app
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        console.log(user.email);
        UserRef.child(user.uid).set(rank.value);
        alert("you have succseffully signed up!!")
      this.props.history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <SignUpView onSubmit={this.handleSignUp} />;
  }
}

export default withRouter(SignUpContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a `Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential>` object. The `uid` property is nested inside the `firebase.auth.UserCredential.user` property.

Please try this updated code:

```
try {
  const userCredential = await app
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);

    console.log(userCredential.user.email);
    UserRef.child(userCredential.user.uid).set(rank.value);

    alert("you have succseffully signed up!!")
  this.props.history.push("/");
} catch (error) {
  alert(error);
}
```